# Duplicate entries on partition key in Cassandra

Tags: database-design, cassandra, nosql

I have question related to Cassandra partitioning. I have a table

```sql
CREATE TABLE books (
   isbn text,
   title text,
   author text,
   publisher text,
   category text,
   timestamp text,
   PRIMARY KEY (timestamp)
);
```

I want to make partitions based on timestamp and my timestamp is date time in minutes. So, in some cases this timestamp will repeat.

If I understand Cassandra correctly, when same timestamp entry is inserted then what it will do is update the entry having that timestamp.

Which is not what I want in my case. I want timestamp as my partition, but I also want duplicate timestamps entries.

Doesn't it contradict the whole primary key based partition if you cannot enter duplicate entries.

I am new to Cassandra so I may be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Partitions keys in Cassandra have to be universally unique because they identify a unique partition (record) in your cluster.

In Cassandra when you insert a new record with the same partition key, it causes an "upsert" meaning the partition gets overwritten with the new values.

As a side note, it makes no sense to use an artificial key for your tables. ISBN is universally unique so you should use it to partition your `books` tables.

If you want to keep multiple versions of books in the table, I'd recommend modelling your table accordingly. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE books_by_isbn (
   isbn text,
   version timestamp,
   title text,
   author text,
   publisher text,
   category text,
   PRIMARY KEY (isbn, version)
)
```

In this table, each book is identified by its ISBN and there are multiple rows inside each partition that are identifiable by the `version` column. Cheers!

Comment: Ooh, nice pickup on the typo @Andrew. Thanks for the edit, mate! 

Comment: Is that correct? I think the primary key needs to be Unique, which is partition key(s) + clustering key. Not only partition key.

Comment: @html_programmer the clustering key(s) identify a row within a partition. The unique partition key is what identifies a specific partition in a table. Cheers!

Comment: But in the example given, isbn is the partition key and version is the clustering key, which together form the primary key. 
So I can have multiple rows with the same isbn and different version in the same table. Therefore the partition key doesn't have to be unique or I am wrong?

Comment: You are correct that in my example table, each `isbn` has multiple `version` (rows). But the partition key has to be unique. I don't follow what you mean in your comment. Perhaps you need to restate it? Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It can happen when you have clustering keys along with partition keys.

Here is the example:
`app_name` and `env` are partition keys and are same for below 2 rows but still with different clustering key(`log_datetime`) it allows a new entry.
[image]

Table structure:
[image]